# Extracting data with JSOUP

Tags: jsoup

I am working on API that has to extract data from a website.

Website source code example:

```
<td class="a">Date 1</td>
<a class = b">Comment</a>
<a class = b">Comment</a>
<a class = b">Comment</a>
<a class = b">Comment</a>

<td class="a">Date 2</td>
<a class = b">Comment</a>
<a class = b">Comment</a>
<a class = b">Comment</a>

<td class="a">Date 3</td>
<a class = b">Comment</a>
<a class = b">Comment</a>
<a class = b">Comment</a>
```

I am looking to extract data with JSOUP into 3 separate views according to dates.

So basically I want to use Elements elements = document.select("a[class=b]"); so that it will only select data between Date 1 and Date 2, Date 2 and Date 3, Date 3 and ...

I tried using nextSibling() and hasNext() but it seemed not to work.

Answer (score 0):

There a few ways to handle this, in combination of code or selectors.   The easiest would be to work in code (in my opinion):

```
Elements elements = document.select("a[class=b]");
for (Element bElements : elements) {
     for (Element nextElement = bElements.getNextElementSibling(); !nextElement.className().equalsIgnoreCase("b"); nextElement = nextElement.getNextElementSibling()) {
          // Do something with this element between the b classes (nextElement)
     }
}
```

You can also do something in the selectors to using the CSS select ~ and the :not to capture 
the elements between specific TDs but this gets messy...

Hope this helps!